# File not overwritten though opened in 'w' mode in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, file, io

As in everywhere this piece of code should overwrite content on the file with the value in the `last_index` variable because the file is opened in `w` mode.

```py
from threading import *

def function():
    with open('important.cache', 'w') as f:
        while True:
            f.write(str(last_index))

mythread = Thread(target=function)
mythread.start()
```

but my `important.cache` file looks like this,

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111122222222222222222222222222222222222222333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333334444444444444444444444444444444555555555555555555
```

I want it to look like,

```
0
```

this should be overwritten in every cycle of the loop.
So it can be

```
1
```

or

```
2
```

or

```
the value of the variable last_index at that time
```

Comment: You're opening it once and writing in it infinitely. Your file is only overwritten if you close and reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should maybe switch the order of your loops. It is true as you say that `'w'` mode erases the content of the file, but it does it when you call the `open` function instead of when you call `write`.

```
from threading import *

def function():
    while True:
        with open('important.cache', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(last_index))

mythread = Thread(target=function)
mythread.start()
```

You'll see that sometimes the `important.cache` file will be empty. This is because the while loop is very very fast and it is erasing and writing the file very fast. For solving that, you should maybe call a small sleep after the write statement (`time.sleep(0.01)`) would probably work.

Comment: can you please explain the answer

Comment: Yes! Check it now. I modified my answer. Don't forget to accept my answer if it works for you :D

Comment: Or even consider what situation you want the loop to stop and have your break case after the write.